# Managing states of toggle button

Tags: java, android, adt

The issue I am having is managing the states of a togglebutton being on and off. The button turns bluetooth on/off. How can I make it so the button can be toggled readily on and off without closing the app? Right now it only works when launching the application.

```
if(!myBluetooth.isEnabled()){

            final ToggleButton tglbtn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);

            tglbtn.setChecked(false);
           tglbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                    myBluetooth.enable();}});

            }

        else {
            ToggleButton tglbtn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);

            tglbtn.setChecked(true);

          tglbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
           public void onClick(View v) {
            myBluetooth.disable();}});
        }
```

I tried implementing a loop to accomplish this, but the app kept crashing, the only other thing I could think of is a `goto` down at the bottom below the two myBluetooth instance's, linking to the other one but since that's not possible in java, I'm out of ideas.

```
while(myBluetooth != null){
             tglbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                    myBluetooth.enable();
                    toggleflag = true; }});
                    while (toggleflag){
                        tglbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                myBluetooth.disable();
                                toggleflag = false; }});

                    }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), buttonView.isChecked()+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks, ill try it. Got it to work with `tglbtn.setChecked(myBluetooth.isEnabled());`

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the state using**

[isChecked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked%28%29)